# Pytest django generic relation old object appeared

Tags: python, django, celery, pytest

I have a model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    url = models.TextField(blank=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Store(models.Model):
    product = GenericRelation('Product')
```

And celery task that creates a product for store:

```
def my_celery_task(store_obj_pk):
    store_obj = Store.objects.get(pk=store_obj_pk)
    Product.objects.create(
                      content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(store_obj),
                        object_id=store_obj.pk,
                    )
```

And I want to test this task with pytest

```
class TestStoreTask:

    def test_store_one(self):
        self.__test_store(store_product={
            'name': 'one'
        })

    def test_store_two(self):
        self.__test_store(store_product={
            'name': 'two'
        })

    def __test_store(self, store_product):

        store_obj = Store.objects.create()
        my_celery_task(store_obj_pk=store_obj.pk)
        print(store_obj.product.all())
```

So I expect one object for each test. But when I run both tests in `test_store_two` I have two objects. And this objects have id 2 and 3.

So my output for `test_store_one`:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Product object (1)>]>
```

And for `test_store_two`:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Product object (2)>, <Product: Product object (3)>]>
```

I don't understand why id was changed and why object appeared in new test case.

Comment: do you use `pytest-django` for testing? It rolls back all transactions made at the end of the test, so the behaviour you observe is the expected one.

Comment: @hoefling yes, I use, but why my new object that i created in second function, contains 2 generic relation objects with different ids. I have Store_obj id(1) in first test and Store_obj(2) in second test.

Comment: how to avoid this...

Comment: Can you add your `Product` model so I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: @hoefling
```
class Product(models.Model):
    url = models.TextField(blank=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

like this

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue in a new project, using the models and tests code you've provided (btw they are correct from what I can tell). I get `<QuerySet [<Product: Product object (1)>]>` printed in both tests. You will have to extract the vital pieces of code in a [mcve] and updated your question with them.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for helping, check my answer, maybe you know why this happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hoefling thanks for helping. It was very weird behaviour. So creating object in task, was a method of another class, like:

```
    class SomeManagerClass:
        products = []

        def generate_products(self):
            self.products.append('one')

        def create_products(self, store_obj):
             for title in self.products:
                 Product.objects.create(
                      title=title,
                      content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(store_obj),
                      object_id=store_obj.pk,
                    )
```

And in task I used it like:

```
def my_celery_task(store_obj_pk):
    store_obj = Store.objects.get(pk=store_obj_pk)
    manager = SomeManagerClass()
    manager.generate_products()
    manager.create_products(store_obj)
```

And when I call `my_celery_task` twice, then I get 3 objects, instead of two. Because `self.products` previous result keep alive.

I solved this by modify my `generate_products` function like:

```
def generate_products(self):
    self.products = []
    self.products.append('one')
```